# Azure VM cannot join domain controller

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, azure, domain-controller

I have setup a VM that is configured to be a Domain Controller and a second VM that I want to join to this Domain Controller. Both VM's are in the same Vnet with an Azure Private DNS Zone connected to this Vnet. Both VM's are in separate subnets and are able to ping each others private IP's and I am also able to ping the FQDN of my DC. Issue comes when I try to join the domain controller I get the following error message.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJ5YM.png)

Issue is I am sure I have configured the A record correctly and I am able to ping the FQDN, so I am not sure why my VM cannot join the domain controller?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4h0V.png)

Comment: Have you configured your domain controllers to use the private DNS zone instead of windows DNS? It is not just A records that need to be created, AD needs to create a load of SRV records

Answer (score 0):

You need to set DNS on the NIC or VM Level to point to the VM handling DNS request